# WinError 10014 when using futures.ThreadPoolExecutor to execute web socket calls asynchronously

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, concurrent.futures

I am using `futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()` to execute web socket calls asynchronously.

My function receive a list of message, send them over the web socket, waits for each of the response and return a list of response.

```
def batch(self, messages: List[Dict]) -> List:
    response = []
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        future_to_msg = {executor.submit(send, msg): msg for msg in messages}
        for future in futures.as_completed(future_to_msg):
            m = future_to_msg[future]
            try:
                resp = future.result()
                except Exception as exc:
                    print(m)
                    response.append(str(exc))
                else:
                    response.append(resp)
        return response
```

And the `send(message: str)` basically sends the message over the web socket and waits for the response using `SettableEvent()`

This works fine most of the times.

But sometime it fails with

> [WinError 10014] The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call

followed by

> <WebSocketConnectionError message=socket is already closed.>

I have tried with less than number of `max_workers` in `ThreadPoolExecutor()` to limit the resource usage but behavior is same.

what could go wrong when it fails? is there any issue with my implementation?

I am running this with a list of 2k messages